# How do I get the body of an HTTP 403 response using Python+aiohttp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, http-status-code-403, aiohttp

I'm using Python 3.6 and the aiohttp library to make an API Post request to a server.  If I use the wrong username when making the request, I get an HTTP 403 error as I expect.  When I make this request in Postman, the body of the response shows:

```
{"error_message": "No entitlements for User123"}
```

When I make the request using aiohttp however, I don't see this response body anywhere.  The message just says "Forbidden".  How can I get the error message above in my Python code?

Edit:  Here's my aiohttp code, although it's pretty straightforward:

```
try:
    async with self.client_session.post(url, json=my_data, headers=my_headers) as response:
        return await response.json()
except ClientResponseError as e:
    print(e.message)  # I want to access the response body here
    raise e
```

Edit 2: I found a workaround.  When I'm creating the `client_session`, I set the raise_for_status value to False.  Then when I get a response from the API call, I check if the status is >= 400.  If so, I handle the error myself, which includes the body of the response.

Edit 3: Here's the code for my workaround:

```
self.client_session = ClientSession(loop=asyncio.get_event_loop(), raise_for_status=False)
####################### turn off the default exception handling ---^

try:
    async with self.client_session.post(url, json=my_data, headers=my_headers) as response:
    body = await response.text()

    # handle the error myself so that I have access to the response text
    if response.status >= 400:
        print('Error is %s' % body)
        self.handle_error(response)
```

Comment: Show your `aiohttp` code

Comment: @Alderven I edited just now to include my code

Comment: Try to read response as bytes or as text instead of json (`await response.read()` or `await response.text()`). May be that problem in content type of response or in other place.

Comment: @YuriiKramarenko control never reaches that `return await response.json()` line.  It skips right to the `except` block

Comment: @user2023861 Show your `ClientSession` initialization please

Comment: @user2023861 You should use `raise_for_status()` that basically raises and error if the status code is >= 400. The link from official docs: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.raise_for_status

Comment: @user2023861 also workaround, that you find, is correct. Just remove `raise_for_status` from your `ClientSession` initialization and process error in `RequestContextManager`

Comment: @YuriiKramarenko I edited my question to include my workaround code.  I don't know enough about the RequestContextManager to change it, but my workaround is pretty simple

Comment: @BogdanCondurache that raise_for_status() function raises a ClientResponseError that doesn't include the response body.  I need access to the response body.  Hence my question

Comment: @user2023861 `async with self.client_session.post(url, json=my_data, headers=my_headers) as response` returns you `RequestContextManager`. You can't access response body outside of it. So just use workaround that you already found

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it may be indeed confusing if you are coming from `requests` package that has its exception objects having `.request.response` (or the other way around) attribute.

You've already figured that out obviously, but here is a proper answer for the **older versions** of aiohttp.

```
async with session.post(...) as response:
    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except ClientResponseError as err:
        logger.error("Error: %s, Error body: %s", err, (await response.text()))

    return await response.json()
```

The newer versions unfortunately recycle the connection once `raise_for_status()` is called hence you can't fetch the error body later. Here is what work for me nowadays (from [http-noah](https://github.com/haizaar/http-noah/blob/master/http_noah/async_client.py#L203) package):

```
        logger = structlog.get_logger(__name__)

        async with session.post(url, **req_kwargs) as res:
            # Fetching text as error just in case - raise_for_status() will
            # release the connection so the error body will be lost already.
            # The text will be cached in the response internally for the use later on
            # so no waste here.
            err_body = await res.text()
            try:
                res.raise_for_status()
            except aiohttp.ClientResponseError as err:
                logger.error("Request failed", err=err, err_body=err_body)
                raise
```

Comment: This code still gives me a "Connection closed" exception when trying to read the response text in the exception handler (aiohttp 3.7.3, python 3.6) File ".../site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 344, in read
    raise self._exception
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectionError: Connection closed

Comment: You are right - in aiohttp 3.7.x (I think) they've "fixed" it by causing `raise_for_status()` to recycle the connection back into pool. Here is what works: https://github.com/haizaar/http-noah/blob/master/http_noah/async_client.py#L203